# E: Unable to locate package passenger

Tags: 14.04, nginx, beagleboard

I need to install Nginx with passenger on BeagleBone, so I tried all the steps up to `sudo apt-get install -y nginx-extras passenger` from this website: [Installing Passenger + Nginx on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (with APT)](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/nginx/install/oss/trusty/). When I tried to install nginx passenger by using following command:

```
sudo apt-get install -y nginx-extras passenger
```

but unexpectedly I am getting an `unable to locate package` error message.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package passenger
```

Do I need to any of traditional package to resolve this issue?

Comment: Before trying to install nginx with passenger in Ubuntu 14.04 did you install the PGP key and add https support for apt by running this command: `sudo apt-get install -y dirmngr gnupg && sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 561F9B9CAC40B2F7 &&
sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates` ?

Comment: @karel Yes I did the installation step by step only.

Comment: Now I understand what you did, but I have another question. Did you follow the step-by-step installation instructions at [Installing Passenger + Nginx on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (with APT)](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/nginx/install/oss/trusty/)?

Comment: Yes I tried all the step upto sudo apt-get install -y nginx-extras passenger from this web site.